# Can doctrine:schema:update be restricted to a subset of available entities?

Tags: doctrine-orm, phpunit, symfony

I'm currently working on a Symfony 3 bundle that has the functionality of generating some boiler plate code. I would like to test the correctness by using phpunit. For this I think it would be best to generate some test cases (among which there will be source code of classes which will have the @Entity annotation) and have Doctrine update the database of the test environment with only the entities that are needed to perform the test. Afterwards the respective tables could be safely dropped again.

But I don't know an easy way for doing this. Since my bundle may one day be installed on an incomplete project I'd prefer it not to be necessary to update the whole schema just to test this bundle, when the test might even fail.

I am aware of Doctrine's `Schema` class but I was wondering if a more practical solution was available? The problem there is you can create the tables etc with it but I guess there won't be any mapping then?

Google wasn't very helpful, so I suspect I'm deviating a bit from 'normal' usage here. Also, if I am violating any best practices in my approach or I need to rethink my design I'd like to hear about it.

To be clear I want to:

- generate a class with @Entity (and maybe others) annotation(s), this I'm already doing
- have doctrine update the schema to include only these classes
- have mapping for these classes available at next execution

Thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good practices for database testing with doctrine on a standalone bundle/library are hard to find.

So, I will give you the way I use:

1) A specific database

For this, you can create specific configuration files including your database configuration, that would be different from the one used by your other environments, or simply [define environment variables](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.php-ini-constants-variables) in your phpunit configuration.

For create a temporary database during the test phase:

```
/**
 * Create database.
 */
public static function createDatabase($path)
{
    $config = [
        'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'user'     => 'forge',
        'password' => 'forge',
    ];

    $tmpConnection = \Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($config);

    // If the db exists, do nothing
    if (in_array('db_name', $tmpConnection->getSchemaManager()->listDatabases())) {
        return;
    }

    // Create the db
    $tmpConnection->getSchemaManager()->createDatabase($GLOBALS['db_name']);

    $tmpConnection->close();
}
```

2) A specific mapping

For this, you can:

- Generate entities by using the doctrine [EntityGenerator](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/EntityGenerator.php) ([example](https://github.com/chalasr/doctrine-test-util/blob/master/lib/RCH/DoctrineTestUtil/Entity/EntityCreator.php)).
- Load existing entities by adding them to [your whitelist](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.whitelisting-files) (Or exclude those that you don't want to test).

**Note** If you need to generate them, you'll need to mark the tests as skipped while the entities don't exist.

3) A specific schema

You need to reproduce a database connection (temporary), create your schema at the beginning of your tests and drop it at the end.

The two last phases could be resumed in a lite class:

```
use Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool;
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;

/**
 * Database.
 */
class Db
{
    /** @var EntityManager */
    private $entityManager;

    /**
     * Create db schema.
     */
    public function createSchema() 
    {
        // Location(s) of your mapping
        $mappingPaths = ['Acme/Path/To/Entities', 'Acme/Second/Path/To/Entities', ...];

        // Db config, should be loaded from config files as previously said
        $config = [
            'dbname'   => 'project_test'
            'driver'   => 'pdo_mysql',
            'host'     => 127.0.0.1,
            'user'     => 'forge',
            'password' => 'forge',
        ];

        // Configure and load your mapping
        $metadataConfiguration = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($mappingPaths, true, null, null, false);

        // Create the EntityManager instance
        $em = EntityManager::create($config, $metadataConfiguration);

        $tool = new SchemaTool($em);
        $metadata = $em->getMetaDataFactory()->getAllMetaData();

        // Drop an eventual existing schema
        $tool->dropSchema($metadata);  

        // Create the new schema 
        $tool->createSchema($metadata);

        $this->em = $em;
    }

    /**
     * @return EntityManager
     */
    public function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->em;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public function setUp()
{   
    // Create the schema
    $db = new Db();
    $db->createSchema();

    // Enjoy
    $this->em = $db->getEntityManager();
}
```

Hope this help you.